# Using array index outside of the allocated memory appears fine, how?

Tags: c, arrays

```
int main (){

    int number[5];

    number[0]=45;
    number[1]=12;
    number[2]=555;
    number[5]=89;
    number[6]=46; 

    printf("%d",number[6]); 
}
```

As we know, we're not supposed to access array out-of-bounds. Here, how the `number[6]` can be executable?

Answer (score 4):

> *how the number[6] can be executable*

**<sup>I'll humbly suggest to use *"accessible"* instead of *"executable"*</sup>**

- **Point 1.** Both the `number[5]` and `number[6]` are out of bound. Remember, `C` uses `0` based index for arrays.
- **Point 2.** Accessing out of bound memory causes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). This includes all sorts of strange behaviours.

Answer (score 2):

Going outside the limits of any array leads to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

You have declared number to be an array of size 5. And you are trying to use number[5] and number[6]. This is an undefined behavior.